# converse.js connect is hanging

Tags: javascript, openfire, converse.js

I have used converse.js for creating a chatbox in my website. (https://conversejs.org/)

The second thing I have added is a openfire (http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) xmpp server.

Converse.js however keeps hanging during 'signing' and in the logs of openfire I keep getting unknown_certificate messages.

```
converse.initialize({
            allow_otr: true,
            auto_list_rooms: false,
            auto_subscribe: false,
            bosh_service_url: 'http://localhost:8080/xmpp-bosh', // Please use this connection manager only for testing purposes

            debug: true ,
            hide_muc_server: false,
            i18n: locales['en'], // Refer to ./locale/locales.js to see which locales are supported
            prebind: false,
            show_controlbox_by_default: true,
            xhr_user_search: false,
        }
```

The html containing this code is also on the same host+port so i do not have crossdomain issues. When testing with firebug and chrom-debugger I cannot find any javascript errors either.

Connecting with Pidgin IM messenger works like a charm.
Anyone else encountered this issue when self installing an xmpp service ?

Comment: Please include the relevant code directly in the question. Show us what you have tried as well as why you think it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future googlers.

The problem I was actually having was the midding trailing slash '/' after the bosh_service_url. It seems to be a small thing but with great consequences.

```
bosh_service_url: 'http://localhost:8080/xmpp-bosh/',
```

That seemed to fix the issue for me.